# C# Converting pixel colour to binary

Tags: bitmap, byte, pixel, bit, steganography

For use in a steganography program. I am trying to get the binary equivelant of the R value of a pixel from a bmp, ie: if R value is '255', I want '11111111'.
I am going to loop through the binary value of a letter and replace the least significant bit in each pixel colour (R/G/B) with a bit from the letter so I can retrieve it later.
I have got it working with a string: 
(Reverse is a simple method for reversing the string)

```
private string convToBits(string in_)
        {
            char letter = Convert.ToChar(in_);
            //convert letter to 32-bit int
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(letter);
            //converting 32-bit int to (string) bits
            BitArray ba = new BitArray(new int[] { value });
            string bits32 = "";
            for (int c = 0; c < ba.Length; c++)
            {
                if (c % 8 < 7) //get first 8 bits of the 32bit int
                {
                    //true = 1, false = 0
                    if (ba[c])
                    {
                        bits32 += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bits32 += 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            //get only the first byte of the 32bit (4 bytes) int and reverse using the function below 
            string bitString = Reverse(bits32.Substring(0, 8));       //we now have the letter in binary. 
            return bitString;
        }
```

in_: 'a'

returns: '01100001'

Of course, this doesn't work with a pixel colour as it is upto 3 chars in length (0-255).

What would be the best way of doing this with a value which can range between 0-255?

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Are you showing us a working method, but would like to know a better one?

Comment: The working method is for characters, but I need it for numbers. I have an almost working method for it now but it is always setting the first bit to '0' for some reason. I will work it out hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a different approach when the secret is a string, an image, or anything else. Just read the file in as a byte array (or convert the string to one) and then work with that.

If you think about it, steganography hides bits into other bits. Where these bits come from is irrelevant. This way you can hide a text file, zip file, image file, etc all the same.

Another reason why you should read the bytestream of the file for images is that jpeg, png and other compressed formats take up less space. If you load the pixel array of a jpeg file and then hide those pixels, it'd be like hiding the size of an uncompressed bmp. And you'd add unnecessary complexity to your program just to do all this.

I would do it like this:

- Ask for the filenames of the cover medium and the secret to hide (I'd require the user to write text, if that's what he wants, to a file for the sake of consistency).
- Read the secret file as a byte array.
- Optional: add any other metadata desired, e.g., the size of the secret so that the extractor knows how many bytes to read, the name of the secret file so once extracted it can be saved to that, etc.
- Embed...
- Extract...

---

A piece of advice. Don't convert the bits to strings. I suspect you do so just to visualise the 1s and 0s, but that's extremely inefficient. You're better off working with [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) directly. For example, to embed a bit to a pixel, zero out the lsb with AND and then add the bit with OR.

```
// embed
pixel = pixel & 0b11111110 | secretBit

// extract
secretBit = pixel & 0b00000001
```

Comment: Bit shifting is exactly what I need, I think! I have the bits as string as I was literally just getting the bits of the R/G/B value, taking off the LSB and amending it with a bit from my current letter before convert it back to an int. ie: `int newR = Convert.ToInt32(RFirst7 + LFirst1);` .